# Maven - adding a war dependency to another war

Tags: java, maven, jersey, pom.xml

I'm developing a Jersey webapp that serves as a webhook for chatbots, currently I have a generic service that handles the basic connections and now I want to create a specific app webhook that will be able to use the generic service.

I've already added the generic webapp as a maven dependency and can use it in my workspace, but when deploying to tomcat I get error:

```
[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 .../generic/services/Webhook] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...generic.services.Webhook
```

Generic services pom file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>...-generic-services</artifactId>
<name>...</name>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
            ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>...</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

App services pom file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>...-app-services</artifactId>
<name>...</name>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>..generic.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>...-generic-services</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>...-app-services</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So what I basically want to accomplish is to be able to call the generic services functions from the app service webapp, so for example if in generic service there is a function that receives and returns a json then I want to be able to make a function like this in app and call the generic service function with a json and receive from it.

Comment: Extract reusable code into a jar and import it into both projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a WAR as a Maven dependency. WAR has a specific layout which is understood by Servlet Containers and JEE Servers. This layout is not understood by other tools e.g. Maven which expects dependencies to be JARs.

This problem is normally solved by extracting either a new `services-common` Maven module which stores the shared code or moving the Java code outside of the WAR into a new JAR Maven module.

You can try using [WAR Overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to achieve what you want but it won't be as clean as extracting new JAR Modules.

Comment: Most basically a WAR is not understood as a classpath part for java runtime ...nothing related to Maven itself.